# first-of-type not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style the first of a series of divs, differently:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/mA3j8/

```
.slideshow-img-ctnr {
    backround-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
.slideshow-img-ctnr:first-of-type {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

However, the first div's styling remains the same:

```
<div class="slideshow-style-ctnr">
    <div class="slideshow-nav">
        <div class="slide-right">&rarr;</div>
        <div class="slide-left">&larr;</div>
    </div>
    <!-- end slideshow-nav -->
    <div class="slideshow-img-ctnr">
        <img src="images/stock/fd-3" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- end slideshow-img-ctnr -->
    <div class="slideshow-img-ctnr">
        <img src="images/stock/fd-3" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- end slideshow-img-ctnr -->
    <div class="slideshow-img-ctnr">
        <img src="images/stock/fd-3" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- end slideshow-img-ctnr -->
    <div class="slideshow-img-ctnr">
        <img src="images/stock/fd-3" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- end slideshow-img-ctnr -->
    <div class="slideshow-img-ctnr">
        <img src="images/stock/fd-3" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- end slideshow-img-ctnr -->
    <div class="slideshow-img-ctnr">
        <img src="images/stock/fd-3" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- end slideshow-img-ctnr -->
</div>
```

Comment: `:first-of-type` only works with elements, not classes.

Comment: @j08691 nope http://jsfiddle.net/qM4n4/

Comment: @dabadaba yes: http://jsfiddle.net/qM4n4/1/

Comment: why the hell does if work for two but not for three

Comment: @dabadaba beacuse is the first `p` tag add before any p element even  and you will see even with two. http://jsfiddle.net/qM4n4/2/

Comment: Because it's still qualifying the ELEMENT `p`. The class `.what` is not seen until the second `p`, meaning it is not the first of that type. The first example works because it had the class `.what` and also happened to be the first `p` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `:first-of-type` is used for element *types*, not classes.

You should take a look at [this excellent explanation by @BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107).

---

In this specific instance, you *could* using the following:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXxBL/)

```
.slideshow-style-ctnr :first-child + .slideshow-img-ctnr {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

However, this method will fail if `.slideshow-img-ctnr` isn't an adjacent preceding sibling of the first-child of `.slideshow-style-ctnr`. Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/MBGCN/) where it *wouldn't* work.

Though the above *may* work with the current markup, it would be better just to use the following instead:

[**WORKING EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vxx36/)

```
.slideshow-img-ctnr {
    backround-color: red;       /* Styling shared by the elements */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid blue;      /* This will be overwritten */
}
```

Overwrite the initial border on all preceding sibling elements with class `.slideshow-img-ctnr`:

```
.slideshow-img-ctnr ~ .slideshow-img-ctnr {
    border:1px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not seen that syntax before. Is the logic just: 'if `first:child` *and* `.slideshow-img-ctnr` ?

Comment: @tmyie the logic behind is target `slideshow-img-ctnr` if it is right after the `first-child` of `.slideshow-style-ctnr`.

Answer (score 2):

`.slideshow-img-ctnr:first-of-type` means: element which has class `slideshow-img-ctnr` and which is the first of its type within its parent.

Because element with `slideshow-img-ctnr` class is a div, `:first-of-type` check if that's the first `div` in the parent element. It's not, so the element does not match the selector.